# Change Users path for Windows 7 installs

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am looking into upgrading my PC to use Windows 7 and an SSD. I would like to have Windows and my application files on my SSD to make use of the fast read speeds, and user account data on a large "normal" drive for the purposes of cheap bulk storage.

I have read around and found a few tricks to making this happen *after* installing Windows 7, but they feel a bit hack-ish.

Is there a way to (easily) configure the Windows 7 installer to use a non-default path for User information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i haven't been using **[vLite](http://www.vlite.net/)** (for Vista/7) but with nLite (for 2k/XP) it is possible to change the default patth for the user profile and the programs are closely related, so have a look at it. these are great tools to customize windows installation media.

Comment: I've used nLite extensively for Windows XP in the past. I'll give vLite a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of.

Your best bet is changing your "special folder" locations after the installation.